# mongoaudit: Security through obscurity and how to limit connections from a specific subnet?

Tags: mongodb, security, mongodb-3.2, mongodb-3.4

I run [mongoaudit](https://mongoaud.it) on a server. Those are the `failed` results:

[image]

I don't wish to hide my version number. In my opinion this is [Security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)

> In security engineering, security through obscurity (or security by
>   obscurity) is the reliance on the secrecy of the design or
>   implementation as the main method of providing security for a system
>   or component of a system. A system or component relying on obscurity
>   may have theoretical or actual security vulnerabilities, but its
>   owners or designers believe that if the flaws are not known, that will
>   be sufficient to prevent a successful attack. Security experts have
>   rejected this view as far back as 1851, and advise that obscurity
>   should never be the only security mechanism.

what other MongoDB experts do?

[image]

Howto whitelist networks? I wish to do that, but only know about `net.bindIp`. This only say on which virtual NIC mongod listens. Are there options to restrict a subnet?

Comment: There is also defense in depth.  Relying on obscurity exclusively is a bad idea, but if you can make it just a bit harder for attackers to figure out what they are attacking then that bit helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't wish to hide my version number. In my opinion this is Security through obscurity

Hiding version details is not security through obscurity unless that is the main security measure you rely on. Exposed version details can allow an attacker to easily identify [known security issues](https://www.mongodb.com/alerts/#security-related) rather than having to probe for them. Forcing an attacker to test for known exploits may be useful for an [Intrusion Detection System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) to detect and handle obvious malicious attempt signatures.

I would consider this a low risk if you are following other best practices (eg. limiting network exposure, actively applying security updates, monitoring for intrusion attempts). Putting a reverse proxy in front of your MongoDB deployment may also add unwelcome operational complexity for server discovery and failover.

> Howto whitelist networks? I wish to do that, but only know about `net.bindIp`. This only say on which virtual NIC mongod listens. Are there options to restrict a subnet?

As you've noted, MongoDB's `bindIP` configuration only determines which NIC IP addresses the server listens to (not the client IPs that are allowed to connect). To limit network exposure you need configure solutions at the operating system and/or network infrastructure level (eg. firewalls or VPNs).

The current version of `mongoaudit` includes a link to some suggested resources depending on where your MongoDB deployment is hosted: [How to Configure Allowed Hosts, Firewall, Whitelisting and Blacklisting in MongoDB](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-configure-allowed-hosts-firewall-whitelist-and-blacklist-in-mongodb-84434ed02d3a#.ni6xgd9qy).

For more information, also see [Hardening Network Infrastructure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-network/) and the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) in the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: @FyodorGlebov As at MongoDB 3.4, I'm not sure how to comprehensively remove version information short of using a proxy to limit requests to a subset of whitelisted commands that have been vetted or modifying the source code. An obvious source of version information is the `buildInfo` command, which (as at MongoDB 3.4) does not require authentication. I've have to check the source for any other commands that might return version information, but I'm sure this could be included in other status or command results (eg. server-side `eval`, which requires auth and has been deprecated since 3.0).

Comment: There is an open server issue to require authentication for commands such as `buildInfo` that do not have an evident use case before authentication. See: [SERVER-12143: Make some unauthenticated commands require auth](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12143).

Comment: what reverse proxy do you recommend? I mean with support for mongodb protocol?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov I don't have any specific recommendations for MongoDB-aware proxies. Personally I would not deploy public-facing database servers and would limit direct network exposure to trusted internal networks. In my experience proxies and load balancers tend to get in the way of MongoDB drivers' Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM) behaviour and I'd prefer predictable failover. If access to the database definitely needs to be more public I would use a REST API to filter & limit access to a MongoDB deployment and ensure there are no unauthenticated endpoints exposing server information.

Comment: your linked document 'How to Configure Allowed Hosts, Firewall, Whitelisting and Blacklisting in MongoDB' is not helpful for on-premise MongoDB users. The other two documents are only stretching the surface (overview pages). Is there some comprehensive guide howto secure MongoDB (gold security standard) on premise? Only solution to buy MongoDB consultant for 2 days?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov What further details are you looking for? Firewall & network security is generally outside the scope of MongoDB but there is plenty of information available. The linked post you mention on "How to Configure Allowed Hosts, Firewall, Whitelisting and Blacklisting " is related to the `mongoaudit` tool you are using but I suggested additional references from the MongoDB documentation. The canonical reference is the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) but there may be more specific details for your deployment.

Comment: @FyodorGlebov If you have more specific questions regarding your O/S or deployment environment, perhaps those need to be posed as new questions? This question has two aspects related to `mongoaudit`: exposure of the version number and whitelisting connections. If you want a detailed security review a consultant may be a better option, but you should also be able to get some reasonable suggestions in a community forum if you provide sufficient details for your environment and use case.